# Am I handling this error case correctly?

Tags: android, api, exception, reflection

I am using reflection to called a method in my NumberPicker, here is my code:

```
try {
        // reflection call for
        method = numberPicker.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("changeValueByOne", boolean.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(numberPicker, increment);

    //TODO: Before finalizing should there be back-up code in one of these cases?
    } catch (final NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In case the changeValueByOne method does not exist in the NumberPicker (I'm under the impression it doesn't exist in older APIs) can I put some code like `numberPicker.setValue(numberPicker.getValue() - 1);` and remove the `e.printStackTrace();` from the NoSuchMethodException catch block to make it handle this gracefully?

In other words, instead of using the changeValueByOne method if it doesn't exist it will default to the setValue.  I'd rather use changeValueByOne if it is available because it plays the rotation animation of the NumberPicker where I don't believe setValue does.

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.skytbest.intervaltrainer.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-    rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Your minimum target api is 11, right?

Comment: This is embarrassing... how do I find that again? I'm using Android Studio. I'm almost positive I set it to Ice Cream Sandwhich, but I should probably know how to find out for sure...

Comment: No problems, look in your `manifest.xml` should be => 11

Comment: Do you mean `androidmanifest.xml`? I checked there and I don't see anything like that... I also don't see a `manifest.xml`

Comment: Yes, sorry, `AndroidManifest.xml`. Do you have that file? If so, paste it into your question

Comment: yep, that's all of it

Comment: What's in your build.gradle file?

Comment: Ah, there it is! `minSDKVersion 14`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) requires an API >=11 and your minimum required is greater than that. Therefore, you don't get a compile error for `NumberPicker` because devices with API < 11 can't install it. So you shouldn't need to worry.

If you wanted to change that minimum API then you would do something like

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
{   
     // use this method
}
else
{
     // use this method
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. Do you think I even need the try catch block at all?

Comment: Not for `NoSuchMethodException `